# Is Calculus a requirement to become better at Probability and Satistics?

Tags: calculus, statistics

Is Calculus really required to be better at Statistics and Probability and to be a good Data Scientist?

Arthur Benjamin says in [his TED video](http://www.ted.com/talks/arthur_benjamin_s_formula_for_changing_math_education):

"Very few people actually use calculus in a conscious, meaningful way in their day-to-day lives.  On the other hand, statistics–that’s a subject that you could, and should, use on a daily basis.”

“If it’s taught properly, it can be a lot of FUN. I mean, probability and statistics–it’s the mathematics of games and gambling, it’s…it’s analyzing trends, it’s predicting the future.”

Comment: Yes.  $\phantom{yesyesyesyesyes}$

Comment: I think it's good to know calculus, but in a job situation statistics is entirely done with a computer, never by hand.

Answer (score 3):

While I'm sure there are many on this site who will disagree, I'd like to play devil's advocate for a moment and argue that no, calculus is not really necessary to be a good applied statistician or data science person.

It is true that advanced mathematical techniques, including calculus, are necessary to derive the mathematical theory behind statistical methods.  However, I would like to argue that in general it's not necessary to understand the math behind the statistical method in order to apply the method.

For example, one of the most common methods applied is the t-test.  In order to use the t-test, people need to know a serious of rules regarding when it is and is not appropriate.  They do not, however, need to be able to derive the result that the t-statistic follows a t-distribution.

Comment: @PeterSheldrick Would you argue that someone would be better at performing a t-test if they could derive the t-distribution?

Comment: I believe anyone could perform Statistics and solve problems at hand but I also believe if you understand the mechanism, wouldn't you be a better Analyst. The Question is just about that. Since I am looking for Answers, I will add examples to my Question above.. please read..

Comment: It looks like from the quote he is saying calculus is not meaningful to your daily life, but probability and statistics are!

Comment: You can understand the idea and motivation behind using the t-test without having any clue that it's derivation relies on a normal divided by a chi square! Some better examples of situations where understanding the calculus behind the method would be helpful!

Comment: I'd strongly disagree with the "data science" person part. Most of a data scientists job is to *build the models*. You absolutely cannot build a good model without knowing the inner workings of the techniques. I don't know what pure statisticians do in the real world, but I would also imagine they build models too.

Comment: @Matt The term data science is completely ill-defined. It means many different things to different people. Perhaps you can give an example of a model where the inner workings behind it that you need to understand relate to calculus.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, calculus is required. Statisticians must work with moments. To understand moments, you have to know calculus. It's the same with calculating tail probabilities or using maximum likelihood - you can't effectively do either in a non-textbook application without an understanding of calculus. You may not use it on a daily basis, but you will use it periodically.